# Springboot + Postgres + Docker linking

Tags: spring, postgresql, spring-boot, docker

I have one container of springboot application on docker,and one container of postgres with all the settings.How can I run both of them by linking them together.
The image *springboot-postgresql* corresponds to spring boot application,and *postgres* refers to postgresql.
Postgres is listening to 0.0.0.0,port 5432.

[image]

Please suggest,if there's another way other than making a .yml file and using `docker compose up` .
Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way you can communicate between each container is using docker network,

First, you need to create a network:

```sh
$ docker network create sprintapp
```

Above, the command creates a network named `sprintapp`

Then, you need to specify to a container to be inside the network:

```sh
$ docker run --name [CONTAINERNAME] --network sprintapp [IMAGE]
```

This way, all containers within the network could talk to each other, using [CONTAINERNAME] as the URI to locate it.

More info about this:

[docker run reference](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#network-settings)

[docker network reference](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/network)